# Hadoop Multinode Cluster, slave permission denied

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I'm trying to do multinode cluster (actually with 2 nodes - 1 master and 1 slave) on Hadoop. I follow the instruction [Multinode Cluster for Hadoop 2.x](https://www.edureka.co/blog/setting-up-a-multi-node-cluster-in-hadoop-2.X)
When I execute the order:

```
./sbin/start-all.sh
```

I got the error message for my slave node:

```
slave: Permission denied (publickey)
```

I already modified both `.ssh/authorized_keys` files on master and slave and add the keyprint from `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from master and slave. 
Finally I restarted the ssh with the next command `sudo service ssh restart` also on the both nodes (master and slaves). 
By the executing of the order `./sbin/start-all.sh` I don't have a problem with the master node, but slave node get me back the error message permission denied.
Has anybody some ideas, why I can not see the slave node?

The execution of the `jps` order get me currently next result:

master

```
18339 Jps
17717 SecondaryNameNode
18022 NodeManager
17370 NameNode
17886 ResourceManager
```

slave

```
2317 Jps
```

I think, master is ok, but I have troubles with slave.

Comment: Have you tested the passwordless login to the slave machine after modifying the ssh keys..? and check the key permissions, it should be 600

Comment: yes, from my local machine I can do my login without password, just with `ssh name`. I can also execute hadoop on my slave in the single node mode, it's working. What is not working is a multinode cluster

Comment: Can you post your secure log file content

Comment: sure, can you please tell me the path to the file and exactly the file name?

Comment: It will be under /var/log, you can see by `cat /var/log/secure`

Comment: I don't have any secure file in this directory (in root)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132186/discussion-between-guforu-and-brucewayne).

Comment: @Guforu Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm facing the same problem today

Comment: i know this is an old topic but help :   https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Permission-denied-error-at-the-quot-Confirm-Hosts-quot-step/td-p/211411

Answer (score 0):

After `ssh-keygen` on the Master. Copy the `id_rsa.pub` to the `authorized_keys` using `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys` on all the slaves. Test the password-less ssh using:

```
ssh <slave_node_IP>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have copied the whole hadoop folder from master to slave nodes(for easy replication), make sure that the slave node's hadoop folder has the correct owner from the slave system.

```
chown * 777 <slave's username> </path/to/hadoop>
```

I ran this command on my slave system and it solved my problem.